# InternetCrackUrl returns FALSE, GetLastError is 120

Tags: delphi, soap, wininet

I have a DLL that exports a function.

At one point in that function, [InternetCrackUrl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384376(v=vs.85).aspx) from Wininet is called.

Everything works fine except on one particular computer, where `InternetCrackUrl` returns `FALSE` and `GetLastError` returns `120` (ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED).

I can't see anything special about the computer, it's a desktop machine with Win10 PRO. It works everywhere else, on different computers with different versions of Windows even other computers with Win10.

I've also made a test standalone application that only calls `InternetCrackUrl` and that also works which leads me to believe that it has to be something about the DLL.

Any thoughts on what else I could check?

Comment: It does not make sense for `InternetCrackUrl()` to fail with this error when called in a DLL, but not fail at all when called in an app on the same machine. They should be calling the same function in the same WinInet DLL. So this makes me think that the failure is further down inside the OS. Maybe a dependency that WinInet uses internally is failing, and the error is bubbling up into `InternetCraskUrl()`. Maybe your DLL, or the app that loads it, has a side-by-side manifest that loads a different version of WinInet than the standalone app is loading? Or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Process Explorer to check which `WinInet.dll` was loaded.

I found out that that my DLL was in the same directory as the application that was using it.
In that same directory, there was also some ancient version of `WININET.DLL` from 1997 that somebody must have copied there, and that's what my DLL was loading.

When I deleted the old `WININET.DLL`, the one in System32 was loaded and now it works.